# Why do Ruby instance method invocations behave differently when prefixed with 'self'?

Tags: ruby, self, instances, instance-methods

The two invocations of an instance method carry different semantics. The first call to `bar` works as expected.

```
class T
  def foo
    bar      # <= This works. "bar" is printed.
    self.bar # <= EXCEPTION: `foo': private method `bar' called for ...
  end

  private

  def bar
    puts 'bar'
  end
end

t = T.new
t.foo
```

I'd like to understand why. What causes `self.bar` to have a different semantics, throwing an exception? I'm not interested in the exception per se since I can work around with the dubious removal of the `private` label, but primarily interested in the semantic discussion.

Comment: I thought I knew this one. Then I questioned myself, then I questioned Ruby. IIRC it's something to do with self referencing `T` and not the actual instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Private methods can not be called with explicit receiver like `self`. This means that you can call a private method from within a class it is declared in as well as all subclasses of this class.

[Here](https://www.skorks.com/2010/04/ruby-access-control-are-private-and-protected-methods-only-a-guideline/) is a good article about that. It explains well why code like yours will raise `NoMethodError`.

On [wikibooks](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Ruby_Programming/Syntax/Classes#Declaring_Visibility) there is also a good explanation of visibility levels in ruby.

For the reference you can bypass this with [Object#send](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-send) but generally it is considered as a bad practice to do so.

Comment: Good answer. One might ask why Ruby doesn't see that `self.bar` is being called from within the class and permit it, but all Ruby knows at the time the statement is being executed is that `bar` is being called on an instance of `T`, so she has no choice but to raise the exception.

Comment: @CarySwoveland what about a setter like `private def bar=(value); end` which has to be invoked with an explicit receiver? In that case Ruby permits `self.bar=123` but raises an exception for `t.bar=123`. She seems to be quite aware of the receiver.

Comment: Good point, @Stefan. Presumably that's a special case, else `bar` could not be invoked (without using a form of `send`).  I'm wondering how Ruby implements that. Does she check to see if the method is a setter and if so , look more closely? In a similar vein, I created a private method `class` and found that if I wrote `def m; self.class; end` I got the exception about calling a private method with an explicit receiver. If I wrote `def m; class; end` I got a syntax error, presumably because Ruby regarded `class` as a keyword.

Comment: @CarySwoveland maybe even at the parser level? Either way, there is no _technical_ reason why Ruby doesn't allow private method calls with an explicit receiver of `self`. It can be distinguished just fine.